# How to remove old images in amazon ECR

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecr

I am able to create more than 50 images per day.

I would like to store only last 10 images, how can I do it?

Is there any way how to remove last image when is count of images bigger than 10?

Answer (score 3):

You need to create ECR Lifecycle Policy based on `countType`: `imageCountMoreThan`

```
{
                  "rulePriority": 10,
                  "description": "For any tag, keep last 10 images",
                  "selection": {
                    "tagStatus": "any",
                    "countType": "imageCountMoreThan",
                    "countNumber": 10
                  },
                  "action": { "type": "expire" }
}
```